# Displaying names onmouseover

Tags: javascript, css, onmouseover

I have a photo with several people on a website (made with php) and would like to obtain the following: when the cursor is moved over the face of a person, the name of the person is displayed at the bottom of the photo. After a lot of search, I found some code on another website that was close to what I wanted and after I changed a few things I got it to do (mostly) what I want but I really do not understand much of it and I am convinced there must be a simpler way to do it. The code is copied below. The text "Name1" appears at the bottom of the photo when the cursor is at the position specified by the first "hotspot" class, and the text "Name2" appears when the cursor is at the position specified in the second "hotspot" class.

These are my questions:

1. Could somebody explain how it works, and if it could be simplified
2. Why if I replace Name1 with FirstName LastName the output is on two different lines. Nothing seems to fix this other than placing FirstName, LastName inside a table with a single row, and even then the spacing between words is not right and cannot be controlled
3. Why does this code only work with Google Chrome or Firefox but not with Safari or the Windows browser.

Thanks for any hints, even if partial.

The first batch of code is the css file, the other the php file

```
.hotspot {
position: absolute; 
}
.hotspot + * {
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
}
.hotspot:hover + * {
opacity: 1;
}
.wash {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}


<div style="position: relative; height: 1px; width: 1px;">
<img src="photo.jpg" width=900px>
   <div class="hotspot" style="top: 195px; left: 277px; height: 50px; width: 50px;"> 
   </div>
<div>
    <div class="wash"></div>
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 900; left: 300px;font-size:35px;">
   Name1
   </div>
</div>

<div class="hotspot" style="top: 202px; left: 337px; height: 50px; width: 50px;">. 
</div>
<div>
    <div class="wash"></div>
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 900; left: 300px;font-size:35px;">
Name2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a CSS/browser issue. PHP is not related. You likely can achieve what you want with JS easier.

Comment: @user3783243 would you be able to show me how to do it with JS?

Comment: Sorry, I'm from the PHP side. I don't do much JS. I'd start by researching that route though. Sounds similiar to facebook's tagging so maybe https://1stwebdesigner.com/image-tagging-tutorial/ could help ya?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice starter for you to play with.

```js
console.clear();

data = {
  Isabelle: {
    left: 100,
    top: 23,
    width: 172,
    height: 142
  },
  Clara: {
    left: 284,
    top: 38,
    width: 121,
    height: 191
  },
  Sylvie: {
    left: 412,
    top: 9,
    width: 121,
    height: 191
  },
  Steeve: {
    left: 498,
    top: 79,
    width: 208,
    height: 191
  },
  Jacques: {
    left: 56,
    top: 179,
    width: 157,
    height: 191
  },
  Julie: {
    left: 213,
    top: 178,
    width: 106,
    height: 178
  },
  Amélie: {
    left: 300,
    top: 319,
    width: 139,
    height: 211
  },
  Robert: {
    left: 456,
    top: 282,
    width: 182,
    height: 229
  }
};

// Positions the zones with their event handler setted
let names = Object.keys(data);
names.forEach((n) => {
  let zone = $("<div>");
  zone
    .addClass("imageMapZone")
    .css(data[n])
    .hover(
      function () {
        $(".namezone").text(n);
      },
      function () {
        $(".namezone").text("");
      }
    );
  $(".imageMapContainer").append(zone);
});
```

```css
.imageMapContainer{
  position: relative;
}
.imageMapZone{
  position: absolute;
}
.namezone{
  Font-size: 1.4em;
  min-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageMapContainer">
  <img src="https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/sites/default/files/styles/convert_webp_article_main_image/public/images/2332/people-persons-peoples.jpg?itok=wE8o-yua">
</div>
<div class="namezone"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works great but now I have two more problems: suppose I want to display both first name and last name, separated by a space. The space causes trouble. The second problem is that the position of the zones seems to be dependent on the browser. If I adjust the position for Google Chrome, then it works also with Firefox, but on Safari they are all shifted.

Comment: Never mind the first question in my comment, I have figured it out: if I use "Isabelle" instead of Isabelle, then I can also include a space such as "Isabelle LeCarre". But  I still have trouble with the position of the zones being dependent on the browser .

Comment: Like stated in the answer, it is a starter. The dimensions work if the image is at its 100% size... But if it is resized, there is a need for some more calculations. I won't develop a 100% full proof solution here.

Comment: OK thanks, your code was very helpful. I will do some more experimenting with the dimensions.

Comment: You will need to have the 100% image width and height in the data. Then apply a rule of 3 with the rendered image size.

Comment: I would have `data` structured like `{image:{src:"http://www.somewhere.com", width:200,height:200}, zones:{Isabelle:{...}, Robert:{...}}`

Comment: And then scale up to many images in the dataset... ;)